# Logging Error : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use logging in node js.

This is my logger_service.js

```
var appConfig   = require('../config/service');
var bunyan = require('bunyan');

var logLocation = '/logs/test.log'
var logger = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'TEST',
    streams: [{
        type: 'rotating-file',
        path: logLocation,
        period: '1d',
        count: 21
    }]
});

logger.info('location of log file : ' + logLocation);

module.exports = logger;
```

When I am using this , I am getting the error.

My test.js

```
var moment = require('moment');
var current_date = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY.MM.DD');
var logger = require('./logger_service');

var testing = function () {
    logger.info(current_date)
};

testing();
```

I am getting the following error :

```
➜ test_dir node log-monitor/service/test.js      
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/logs/test.log'
    at Error (native)
```

Please help.
Thank you.

My app.js file.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var moment = require('moment');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Everthing else is running fine except for the logging.

Comment: make sure that file present at this location `'/logs/test.log'`, or you access it from root dir like this `'../logs/test.log'`

Comment: I can do that. But when I deploy it on a server, I cannot  create the required file. Can the creation of files be automated?

Answer (score 0):

Answer mentioned by chandoo is partially workable, but still, you may face the issue as you are using

```
streams: [{
    type: 'rotating-file',
    path: logLocation,
    period: '1d',
    count: 21
}]
```

rotating-file is the main concern here, it is already outlined by bunyan community as below. I faced the same problem and when I removed using "rotating-file" & associated count attributes, everything went well. You might consider too. Try an alternative log rotation option e.g. Linux logrotate tool.

> WARNING on cluster usage: Using bunyan-rotating-file-stream with node.js's "cluster" module can result in unexpected file rotation. You must not have multiple processes in the cluster logging to the same file path. In other words, you must have a separate log file path for the master and each worker in the cluster. Alternatively, consider using a system file rotation facility such as logrotate on Linux or logadm on SmartOS/Illumos. See this comment on issue #117 for details.

Answer (score -1):

I also come across this issue.

I fixed it by creating the log folder manually in the path. and I found one more error as well. I installed dependencies as well but, I dont think its necessary.

**npm install async lodash semver strftime --save**

Change **var logLocation = './logs/test.log';**

add dot before. to add date to your log you have to install bunyan-rotating-file-stream as well.

path: './logs/server-%Y%m%d.log',